# OnMouseClick not detected

Tags: unity, mouse

I created "main script" and in `Start()` created simple cube:

```
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1,2,1);
cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0,0,255);
cube.AddComponent<CubeScript>();
```

and then in CubeScript I have empty `Start()` and `Update()` but in `onMouseDown()` just `Debug.Log("click detected");`

and I can never see log despite clicking on cube.. Any advice? did I missed something?

Comment: Sorry, but you have a typo in `Addcomponent` it should be `AddComponent`

Comment: thanks. it is corrected ;) didn't copy pasted it from the script

Comment: Now your code should work fine. Make sure other things from inspector

Comment: Code was already with AddComponent.. what other things to make sure from inspector? didn't understand that.. :S

Comment: can you post the script of CubeScript and screenshot of new created cube's inspector?

Comment: cube script is literally void Start(){Debug.Log("CubeScript start");} void Update(){} void OnMouseDown(){Debug.Log("click detected");}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35811/discussion-between-ewoks-and-hamza-hasan).

Answer (score 2):

problem actually was that I typed onMouseDown() instead of **O**nMouseDown() .. 
Everybody coming from Java world pay attention!!! MonoDevelop will not warn you that mathod with such a name doesn't exist, but it will just silently ignore the issue.

Thanks a lot to @Malrig & @Hasan .. There were really trying to help me and made me double check what I typed

Comment: By the way there is nothing to warn. If you don't write correct spellings of MonoBehaviour's messages then compiler will consider that a new method, like common other own created methods.

Comment: Just to clarify, it doesn't warn that method doesn't exist because you actually just created it. I'm not sure why these aren't virtual functions though, that way intellisense could show you the valid methods just by typing 'override' .. oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Your cube doesn't have a collider.

Try

```
cube.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
```

See: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: That was my first thought. But the thing is, collider is already attached when you create primitive like this :)

Comment: exactly as Hasan said.. I tried to add BoxCollider2d and got warning that collider is already attached